# Kivy app crashes on android with error module not found sklearn

Tags: python, android, scikit-learn, kivy, kivymd

I have made simple machine learning app which predicts crop for soil report inputs . It works totally fine on windows but however when converted to apk using bulldozer tool with all required requirements it crashes with logcat error module not found sklearn , I have added sklearn in requirements of buildozer.spec file

**Python code***

```
class SoilTest(Screen):
    location = ObjectProperty()
    nitrogen = ObjectProperty()
    phosphorus = ObjectProperty()
    potassium = ObjectProperty()
    rain_fall = ObjectProperty()
    ph  = ObjectProperty()
    temp = ObjectProperty()
    humidity = ObjectProperty()
    def submit_result(self):
        global humi
        humi=self.humidity.text
        o=open("loc.csv","+a")
        p = o.write(humi) 
        humi = float(humi)
        global tem
        tem=self.temp.text
        p = o.write("\t")
        p = o.write(tem)
        tem=float(tem)
        global p_h 
        p_h = self.ph.text
        p = o.write("\t")
        p = o.write(p_h)
        p_h=float(p_h)
        global fall
        fall = self.rain_fall.text
        p = o.write("\t")
        p = o.write(fall)
        fall=float(fall)
        global pota
        pota = self.potassium.text
        p = o.write("\t")
        p = o.write(pota)
        pota=float(pota)
        global phos
        phos = self.phosphorus.text
        p = o.write("\t")
        p = o.write(phos)
        phos=float(phos) 
        loc = self.location.text
        data1 = o.write(loc)
        global nitro
        nitro = self.nitrogen.text
        n = o.write('\t')
        n = o.write(nitro) 
        nitro=float(nitro) 
        o.close()
    def recommand(self):
        x = [[nitro,phos,pota,tem,humi,p_h,fall]]
        y_pred = mode.predict(x);
        global cropi
        cropi=(crop_name[y_pred[0]])
        cropi=str(cropi)
        print(cropi)
```

**Kivy Code**

```
<SoilTest>:
    name:'soiltest'
    location: loc
    nitrogen: nitro
    phosphorus: phosp
    potassium: pota
    rain_fall: rain
    ph: pih
    temp: temper
    humidity: humi
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDTextField:
            id: loc
            hint_text:"Enter Location"
            helper_text:"parameters"
            icon_right:'android'
            helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
            icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.9}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:300
        MDTextField:
            id: nitro
            hint_text:"Enter Nitrogen"
            helper_text:"parameters"
            icon_right:'android'
            helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
            icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.8}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:300
        MDTextField:
            id: phosp
            hint_text:"Enter Phosphorus"
            helper_text:"parameters"
            icon_right:'android'
            helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
            icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.7}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:300
        MDTextField:
            id: pota
            hint_text:"Enter Potasium"
            helper_text:"parameters"
            icon_right:'android'
            helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
            icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.6}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:300
        MDTextField:
            id: rain
            hint_text:"Enter Rain_fall"
            helper_text:"parameters"
            icon_right:'android'
            helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
            icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:300
        MDTextField:
            id: pih
            hint_text:"Enter PH of soil"
            helper_text:"parameters"
            icon_right:'android'
            helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
            icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.4}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:300
        MDTextField:
            id: temper
            hint_text:"Enter Temprature"
            helper_text:"parameters"
            icon_right:'android'
            helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
            icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.3}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:300
        MDTextField:
            id: humi
            hint_text:"Enter Humidity"
            helper_text:"parameters"
            icon_right:'android'
            helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
            icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.2}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:300
        # BoxLayout:
        #     orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                text:"Submit"
                pos_hint:{"center_x":.4,"center_y":.4}
                size_hint_x:None
                on_release:
                    root.submit_result()
                    root.recommand()
                    # (nitro,phosp,pota,temper,humi,pih,rain)
                    app.root.current='result'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'horizontal'        
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                text:"Back"
                pos_hint:{"center_x":.4,"center_y":.4}
                size_hint_x:None
                on_release:
                    app.root.current='first'
```

Here is the images of app logcat
[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN1ux.png)

Here are some ss of app with submit button after pressing this it crashes on android but works fine on windows

[Soil reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amDmc.png)

Predicted crop by app
[crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTEdc.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this code not sufficient?